# "History Time To Live cannot be null | resource Orchestration.bpmn" after upgrading to camunda 7.20

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have upgraded to camunda 7.20 and springboot to 3.x but I am getting below error:-

History Time To Live cannot be null | resource Orchestration.bpmn

I never had set History time before to bpmn files, also Orchestration.bpmn is not found in my workspace.

Stack trace:-

```
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ParseException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors:
* History Time To Live cannot be null: History Time To Live cannot be null | resource Orchestration.bpmn | line 3 | column 56
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EngineUtilLogger.exceptionDuringParsing(EngineUtilLogger.java:66)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.xml.Parse.throwExceptionForErrors(Parse.java:240)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:354)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.transformDefinitions(BpmnDeployer.java:105)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.transformResource(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:99)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.parseDefinitionResources(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:74)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.AbstractDefinitionDeployer.deploy(AbstractDefinitionDeployer.java:64)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:54)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer$1.call(CacheDeployer.java:51)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:559)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:547)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.CacheDeployer.deploy(CacheDeployer.java:51)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.cache.DeploymentCache.deploy(DeploymentCache.java:71)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentManager.insertDeployment(DeploymentManager.java:64)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.deploy(DeployCmd.java:258)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.lambda$doExecute$0(DeployCmd.java:155)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:559)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:547)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.doExecute(DeployCmd.java:141)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:101)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:81)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.lambda$execute$0(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandCounterInterceptor.execute(CommandCounterInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ExceptionCodeInterceptor.execute(ExceptionCodeInterceptor.java:55)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.deployWithResult(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deployWithResult(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:270)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:266)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.autoDeployResources(SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.java:156)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.java:67)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:55)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:34)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:148)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are not using history at all, set enforceHistoryTimeToLive property to false (set to true by default)

```
camunda:
    bpm:
        generic-properties:
            properties:
                enforceHistoryTimeToLive: false
```

if you want to set a specific TTL, use historyTimeToLive property

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    generic-properties:
      properties:
        historyTimeToLive: P1D
```

Answer (score 0):

History time to live is required since 7.20.

If you do not want to add the TTL manually to your process instances, you can define a default using your `application.yml`:

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    generic-properties:
      properties:
        historyTimeToLive: P1D
```

This will set a default of 1 day.

Comment: I just got aware of an even [easier way](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.20/update/minor/719-to-720/#enforce-history-time-to-live): setting `enforceHistoryTimeToLive =false`does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a flag to disable the new requirement of a non-null history TTL.
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.20/update/minor/719-to-720/#enforce-history-time-to-live
If you set the enforceHistoryTimeToLive to false, you'll get the old behavior back.

Answer (score 0):

In case you rely on the old stack (e.g. by testing) and not start Spring Boot, you can insert the following property into your `camunda.cfg.xml` file:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration"
          class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="historyTimeToLive" value="P1D" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```